# Surjective+finite-type+quasi-finite doesn't imply finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Exercise II.3.5 (c) in Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, asks to find an example of a surjective, finite-type and quasi-finite morphism of schemes which is not finite.

I need to find a finitely generated $A$-algebra $B$ which is not finite generated as an $A$-module. The only examples, I could find, of such a kind of $B$ give rise to a morphism which is not quasi-finite. Basically I was trying to use some modification of the classic $B=\mathbb{C}[x]$. I have also thought to  find a morphism which is not closed, since we know that a finite morphism is always closed, but even this way didn't lead me anywhere.

Do you have any suggestion?

P.S.: $f$ quasi-finite means that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite set for every point $y\in Y$.

MOREOVER: while thinking at this example, I asked another question to myself. Which is a quasi-finite morphism which is not of finite-type?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: have you looked at the previous exercise? Is there some way you could mess with this to get something which satisfies your goals?

Comment: @KReiser, thank you for your reply. Do you mean the exercise characterizing finite morphisms or the one stating that a finite morphism is closed? In the first case I cannot see any way to mess anything and in the second case I have actually tried, but the only example I could found was not surjective.

Comment: I mean exercise II.3.4, which asks you to prove that $f:X\to Y$ is finite iff for _every_ open affine $\mathrm{Spec} B = V\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is affine and Spec of some finite $B$-module. What conditions can you violate about this statement?

Comment: Just a cultural note: often finite type is part of the definition of quasifinite, in order to make the concept stable under base change. With these definitions stuff like $k \subset k(x)$ won't count.

Comment: For the problem: could you do it without the surjectivity requirement? We can probably cheat to get around that. The target being the affine line could certainly work.

Comment: @Hoot: Simplest example I know has the affine line as a target and does satisfy the surjectivity requirement. I'm sure there's other good examples, but it might be a good idea to focus on the affine requirement of II.3.4. Are there any non-affine schemes which map nicely to the affine line?

Comment: @KReiser I'd be interested to see your example (of course, we should let the OP think a bit). For what I have in mind, what I mean by "cheating" is that the source could be a disjoint union.

Comment: Without the surjectivity requirement I have thought to the projection from the hyperbola to the affine line.

Comment: @KReiser I am still thinking about your hint.

Comment: @user273503 Okay, good. The problem with that example is that you miss the origin, but why not just add some random point to the hyperbola? Does that cause any problems?

Comment: @KReiser what do you think about the projection $\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{A^1}$? It is quasi-finite, surjective and of finite-type since $\mathbb{P}^1$ can be covered by two copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: @user273503 Could you say what that map is? A map to $\mathbf A^1$ is the same as a regular function, and $\mathbf{P}^n$ does not have many of those.

Comment: @Hoot, sorry I have just noted your last comment. Yeah, it is easy, why I couldn't think about that..?

Comment: @Hoot, I was thinking to map $[x:y]$ to $x$.

Comment: @user273503 that is not even well defined. $[1:0]$ is the same as $[2:0]$ but they map to different places.

Comment: @Hoot, of course it isn't. Forget it, I am stupid. But thinking at $\mathbb{P}^1$ as $\mathbb{A}^1$ plus the point at the infinity, is not possible to find a morphism mapping the $\mathbb{A}^1$ isomorphically on itself and the point at the infinity to some other point?

Comment: @Hoot, anyway coming back to your hint, I cannot see any problem caused by adding an extra point to the hyperbola. I create the scheme $X$ as disjoint union of the hyperbola and the point, in particular it has two connected components and I may define a map from each component to the affine line. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Hopefully we're not both missing something.

Comment: @Hoot, thank you very much for the help. I will try to produce an example by following KReisen too, but now I am happy because I have at least one solution. All the best!

Answer (score 3):

The example given, $Y=\mathbf A^1_k$ for $k$ any field, $X=A\sqcup B$ for $A=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy-1)$, $B=\{\ast\}=\operatorname{Spec} k$, is valid. Here the map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is induced by the map $\varphi:k[x]\rightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)=\Gamma(A\sqcup B,\mathscr O_A\times\mathscr O_B)\cong k[x,y]/(xy-1)\times k$, which is in turn induced by the universal property of the product by the maps $k[x]\rightarrow k[x,y]/(xy-1)$, $k[x]\rightarrow k$. It is obviously quasi-finite; it is of finite type since $X=A\sqcup B$ is a cover of $X$ by open affines and $Y$ is itself affine. Surjectivity of closed points is obvious. Finally, if $\eta$ is the generic point of $A$, and $\xi$ is the generic point of $Y$, then we ask what is $f(\eta)$. If $\mathfrak m\subset\mathscr O_{X,\eta}$ is the maximal ideal of the stalk, and $p_\eta:\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)$ is the map into the stalk, then $f(\eta)$ is the point in $Y$ corresponding to $\varphi^{-1}p_\eta^{-1}(\mathfrak m)$. But now $$\mathscr O_{X,\eta}\cong (k[x,y]/(xy-1)\times k)_{(0,k)}\cong (k[x,y]/(xy-1))_{(0)}=k(x)$$ with $\mathfrak m=(0)$ in that ring, so $f(\eta)$ corresponds to $\varphi^{-1}((0,k))=(0)$.

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph: Do you argue that there is no affine example $\operatorname{Spec}(A) \to \operatorname{Spec}(B)$? But is your first example $X = A \sqcup B$ not just $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y]/(xy-1) \times k)$, hence affine?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I don’t know what that was about

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different example.

Take $X=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z[x]/(3x^2+2x+1)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$. Then $X\to Y$ is clearly finite-type, but not finite since it isn't integral. Furthermore, the fibers over $(p)$ and $(0)$ are $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb F_p[x]/(3x^2+2x+1)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Q[x]/(3x^2+2x+1)$, respectively, which are finite but nonempty, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

One can also find examples over the complex numbers in which the source is irreducible:

Let $f \colon \mathbb{A}^{1} \to \mathbb{A}^{1}$ be the ramified cover given by $z \mapsto z^{2}$ at the level of coordinate rings. Let $i \colon \mathbb{A}^{1} \setminus \{ 1 \} \to \mathbb{A}^{1}$ be the open immersion of the complement of a closed point which is not the origin. Then $f_{0} := f \circ i$ is quasi-finite and surjective, but not proper, hence not finite.

One can check that $f_{0}$ is not proper with the valuative criterion for properness, but the intuititon for this example came from the analytic topology. In fact, when I googled "a finite morphism is closed in the analytic topology" I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1494829/178668) answer, which is exactly the kind of example that I had in mind and seems to confirm the suspicion I had about finite morphisms being closed in the analytic topology (doesn't really confirm it, but it seems that the author was thinking along similar lines at least).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example of a slightly different flavor that might be interesting to some: let $X$ be the line with doubled origin, $Y$ the line, $f:X\to Y$ the obvious map (i.e., the identity on each chart.) Then $f$ is surjective and quasi-finite, since the pre-image of any point has either one or two points. Furthermore, $f$ is finite-type, since $f^{-1}(Y)$ can be covered by affine opens such that the induced maps on rings are finite-type (in fact, they are even finite.) But $f$ is not finite, since finite maps are required to be affine, and this map is not affine.

This highlights a subtle but key difference between the way that finite-type and finite morphisms are defined: finite-type only requires that you can cover the pre-images of affine opens with affine opens that are finite-type, while finite requires that the pre-image of an affine itself be affine and finite. The asymmetry in the definition might seem strange at first, but we want finite-type to be a fairly weak assumption, while finite should be extremely strong.