# Is a quasi-finite closed morphism finite？

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X\to Y$ is a quasi-finite morphism , it is closed on underlying topological spaces, is it a finite morphism? Is there a counterexample? If there is, will it be true if $X$ is a curve?

Comment: Often the definition of quasifinite will include a finite type hypothesis. It seems like you aren't requiring this.

Comment: As long as you include PROPER. In fact, finite is the same thing as quasi-finite plus proper. So, for example, a map between projective objects which is quasi-finite is finite.

Comment: @Hoot Ah..you are right, I should use the definition that it is finite type and  each point $x$ is open in $f^{-1}(f(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:C\to D$ be a finite map of curves, and suppose $c_0\in C$ is a (closed) point that isn't the entire fiber over a point in $D$. Let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to $C\backslash\{c_0\}$. Then $g$ is quasi-finite and closed, but not finite.

For comparison, if $C$ and $D$ are defined over $\mathbb{C}$, then $g$ will not be closed for the analytic topology.

Answer (score 0):

The map $\operatorname{Spec}\overline{ \Bbb{Q}} \to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb{Q}$ is quasi-finite and closed because it is a map between one point spaces. However it is not a finite morphism.

Comment: Will it be true if both $X,Y$ are finite type over the same field $k$?

Comment: @mqx How about an open embedding?